# Is there a non-complete and non-separate metric space?

Tags: metric-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Is there a (non-trival) non-complete and non-separate metric space? Some notions are here: math.stackexchange.com/questions/182316.

Comment: You mean "non separable".

Comment: $\ell_\infty\oplus c_{00}$?

Comment: How about the set of all real-valued functions with finite support on an uncountable set, with e.g. the Euclidean metric?

Comment: @DavidMitra A zero too many?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff One zero would give the (complete) space of sequences converging to $0$. Two zeroes denotes the space of sequences that are eventually zero (intended with the sup norm in my last comment). I thought the notation was fairly standard now...

Comment: @DavidMitra Oh. I'll adopt your notation from now on. =)

Comment: @DavidMitra I can't really what you mean \ell_\infty\oplus c_{00},and it can really naturally be a non separable and non complete metric space?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Ah ha, yes, you are right.

Comment: It's the set with elements of the of the form $(x,y)$ with $x\in\ell_\infty$ and $y\in c_{00}$. The norm of $(x,y)$ is $\Vert x\Vert_\infty+\Vert y\Vert_\infty$ (I should have specified the norm for the "sum"; actually, any norm on the sum will do). It's not separable since $\ell_\infty$ isn't and not complete since $c_{00}$ isn't.

Comment: @DavidMitra No, I know what you said yesterday. I just don't know what is c_{00}, "Two zeroes denotes the space of sequences that are eventually zero", and is it just the small l_p(where p=1)?

Comment: $c_{00}$ is the space of infinite real-valued sequences $(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$ such that $x_i=0$ for $i$ sufficiently large, equipped with the $\sup$ norm.